# How do I line up elements when using css-grid and flexbox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, css-grid

The buttons in the bottom row of the calculator (picture below) do not line up with the buttons above.

The red div is using css grid and the green one is using flexbox. I set the margin for all of those divs as 5px, but the green one is misaligned from the red margins. I've also tried setting the gap using flex and grid's built in methods, but that resulted in nearly the same thing.

How can I change the css such that the buttons in the bottom row are aligned with the buttons above them?

[Current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRfKF.png)

```js
const add = function(a, b) {
    return a+b;
}

const subtract = function(a, b) {
    return a-b;
}

const multiply = function(a, b) {
    return a*b;
}

const divide= function(a, b) {
    return a/b;
}

const operate = function(operator, a, b) {
    if (operator === add || operator === subtract || operator === multiply || operator === divide) {
        return operator(a, b);
    }
   else {
        return;
    }
}


let maindiv = document.createElement("div");
maindiv.id = "main";
document.body.append(maindiv);

let textboxdiv = document.createElement("div");
textboxdiv.id = "textbox";
// maindiv.append(textdiv);

let topdiv = document.createElement("div");
topdiv.id = "topdiv";
maindiv.append(topdiv);

let middlediv = document.createElement("div");
middlediv.id = "middlediv";
maindiv.append(middlediv);

let bottomdiv = document.createElement("div");
bottomdiv.id = "bottomdiv";
maindiv.append(bottomdiv);


let buttons = [];
let divs_top= [];
let divs_middle = [];
let divs_bottom = [];


let top_labels = ["Clear", "Enter"];
let middle_labels = ["1", "2", "3", "+", "4", "5", "6", "-", "7", "8", "9", "*"];
let bottom_labels = ["0", "/"];

function makeButtonsFromList (list, div, divs, buttons) {
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        buttons[i] = document.createElement("button");
        buttons[i].id = "x"+list[i];
        buttons[i].textContent = list[i];
        divs[i] = document.createElement("div");
        divs[i].id = "x"+list[i];
        divs[i].appendChild(buttons[i]);
        div.appendChild(divs[i]);
    }
}

makeButtonsFromList(top_labels, topdiv, divs_top, buttons);
makeButtonsFromList(middle_labels, middlediv, divs_middle, buttons);
makeButtonsFromList(bottom_labels, bottomdiv, divs_bottom, buttons);

divs_bottom[1].id = "x";
```

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
    
}


button {
    color: black;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    
    /*
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    */

}


#main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0 auto;

    width: 760px;
    height: 470px;

}

#topdiv>div, #middlediv>div, #bottomdiv>div {
    margin: 5px;
    height: 50px;
}

#topdiv{
    display: flex;
    /* border: solid 1px yellow; */
    
}
#topdiv > div {
    flex: 1;
}

#middlediv{
    border: solid 1px red;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    /*
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 5px;
    flex-grow: 2;
    justify-content:space-evenly;
    */
}

#middlediv > div {
    height: 50px;


}

#bottomdiv{
    border: solid 1px green;
    display: flex;
   
}

#x0 {
    flex: 3;
}

#x {
    flex: 1;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>See you Calcu-later</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The green and red lines are perfectly aligned. Zoom in and you can see that the green and red borders are drawn on the exact same pixel. Am I missing something?

Comment: Oh, are you talking about the way the "/" button is wider than the other buttons in that column?

Comment: The lines of the green and red boxes are aligned. The lines may appear misaligned due to chromatic aberration (see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_aberration). The lines should appear perfectly aligned if they are the same color.

Comment: @Joshua Craven I may have phrased that incorrectly, I meant that the / button is wider than the others in the column. I just added the red and green border to make it easier to ask the question, sorry about the mix up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought about this a bit and I refactored your code to make it much less complex. We don't have to worry about top, middle, bottom, etc. We can just render all the buttons and their div parents directly into the `#main` div. Then we can use a `grid-template-area` to render them exactly how we want.

Here's a quick preview of the CSS. See the full snippet below for the full implementation. I think you'll find it to be a much more efficient way to accomplish your goal.

```
#main {
        display: grid;
        width: 760px;
        height: 470px;
        row-gap: 10px;
        column-gap: 10px;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
        grid-template-rows: auto;
        grid-template-areas:
            "xClear xClear xEnter xEnter"
            "none none none none"
            "none none none none"
            "none none none none"
            "x0 x0 x0 slash";  
      }
      
    .xClear{
        grid-area: xClear;
    }
    
    .xEnter{
        grid-area: xEnter;
    }
    
    .x0{
        grid-area: x0;
     }

     .x/{
        grid-area: slash;
     }
```

```js
const add = function(a, b) {
    return a+b;
}

const subtract = function(a, b) {
    return a-b;
}

const multiply = function(a, b) {
    return a*b;
}

const divide= function(a, b) {
    return a/b;
}

const operate = function(operator, a, b) {
    if (operator === add || operator === subtract || operator === multiply || operator === divide) {
        return operator(a, b);
    }
   else {
        return;
    }
}


let maindiv = document.createElement("div");
maindiv.id = "main";
document.body.append(maindiv);

let textboxdiv = document.createElement("div");
textboxdiv.id = "textbox";

let buttons = [];
let divs =[];
let labels = ["Clear", "Enter", "1", "2", "3", "+", "4", "5", "6", "-", "7", "8", "9", "*", "0", "/"];

function makeButtonsFromList (list, divs, buttons) {
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        buttons[i] = document.createElement("button");
        buttons[i].id = "x"+list[i];
        buttons[i].textContent = list[i];
        divs[i] = document.createElement("div");
        divs[i].classList.add("x"+list[i]);
        divs[i].appendChild(buttons[i]);
        maindiv.appendChild(divs[i]);
    }
}

makeButtonsFromList(labels, divs, buttons);
```

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
}

button {
    color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;   
}

#main {
        display: grid;
        width: 760px;
        height: 470px;
        row-gap: 10px;
        column-gap: 10px;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
        grid-template-rows: auto;
        grid-template-areas:
            "xClear xClear xEnter xEnter"
            "none none none none"
            "none none none none"
            "none none none none"
            "x0 x0 x0 slash";  
      }
      
    .xClear{
        grid-area: xClear;
    }
    
    .xEnter{
        grid-area: xEnter;
    }
    
    .x0{
        grid-area: x0;
        }
     .x/{
        grid-area: slash;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>See you Calcu-later</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `#x0 { flex-basis: 558px; }` to achieve your desired result.

```js
const add = function(a, b) {
    return a+b;
}

const subtract = function(a, b) {
    return a-b;
}

const multiply = function(a, b) {
    return a*b;
}

const divide= function(a, b) {
    return a/b;
}

const operate = function(operator, a, b) {
    if (operator === add || operator === subtract || operator === multiply || operator === divide) {
        return operator(a, b);
    }
   else {
        return;
    }
}


let maindiv = document.createElement("div");
maindiv.id = "main";
document.body.append(maindiv);

let textboxdiv = document.createElement("div");
textboxdiv.id = "textbox";
// maindiv.append(textdiv);

let topdiv = document.createElement("div");
topdiv.id = "topdiv";
maindiv.append(topdiv);

let middlediv = document.createElement("div");
middlediv.id = "middlediv";
maindiv.append(middlediv);

let bottomdiv = document.createElement("div");
bottomdiv.id = "bottomdiv";
maindiv.append(bottomdiv);


let buttons = [];
let divs_top= [];
let divs_middle = [];
let divs_bottom = [];


let top_labels = ["Clear", "Enter"];
let middle_labels = ["1", "2", "3", "+", "4", "5", "6", "-", "7", "8", "9", "*"];
let bottom_labels = ["0", "/"];

function makeButtonsFromList (list, div, divs, buttons) {
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        buttons[i] = document.createElement("button");
        buttons[i].id = "x"+list[i];
        buttons[i].textContent = list[i];
        divs[i] = document.createElement("div");
        divs[i].id = "x"+list[i];
        divs[i].appendChild(buttons[i]);
        div.appendChild(divs[i]);
    }
}

makeButtonsFromList(top_labels, topdiv, divs_top, buttons);
makeButtonsFromList(middle_labels, middlediv, divs_middle, buttons);
makeButtonsFromList(bottom_labels, bottomdiv, divs_bottom, buttons);

divs_bottom[1].id = "x";
```

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
    
}


button {
    color: black;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    
    /*
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    */

}


#main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0 auto;

    width: 760px;
    height: 470px;

}

#topdiv>div, #middlediv>div, #bottomdiv>div {
    margin: 5px;
    height: 50px;
}

#topdiv{
    display: flex;
    /* border: solid 1px yellow; */
    
}
#topdiv > div {
    flex: 1;
}

#middlediv{
    border: solid 1px red;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    /*
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 5px;
    flex-grow: 2;
    justify-content:space-evenly;
    */
}

#middlediv > div {
    height: 50px;


}

#bottomdiv{
    border: solid 1px green;
    display: flex;
   
}

#x0 {
    flex-basis: 558px;
}

#x {
      flex: 1
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>See you Calcu-later</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know what caused the misalignment? (Just curious)